# Android Cursor retrieve belongsTo relationshoips

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have two data models `Item` and `Category` with the relationship "`Item` belongs to `Category`"

Naturally my database has an `Item.category_id` column.

When I retrieve data using `SQLiteDatabase#query()` it returns a cursor with the data for the passed table name. How can it also retrieve related data (in this case, the category)?

*PS: I'm trying to avoid `rawQuery()` but if that's the only way then...*

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a regular Query. I'm making the assumption you have the id of the item and want to fetch the Category.

*I'm also making the assumption you know what I mean by/how to create your own `Contract` & `Provider`, if you don't, look up database providers on the official docs or let me know*

```
String[] args = { String.valueOf(myItemId) };
getContentResolver().query(MyCategoryContact.CONTENT_URI, null, MyCategoryContact.ITEM_ID + " = ?", args, null);
```